# Conflicts between localhost and Local IP address - OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I'm having some troubles trying to visualize a tile-based map using OpenLayers.

My whole application (html, css, js and maptiles) is deployed on VirtualBox. But, when I try to access from my local machine to the map using a web browser, the map doesn't appear.

The JavaScript file contains the following lines:

```
var tiles = new ol.layer.Tile({
    title: 'Natural Earth',
    type: 'base',
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/www/ol_map3/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        attributions: 'Made with Natural Earth and TilesXYZ'
    })
})

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [tiles],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-4.72, 41.66]),
        zoom: 5
    }),
    renderer: 'canvas'
});
```

However, if I change the url of the tiles' source, using the local IP (192.168.56.101), the map appears on my local machine.
I don't understand what's happening...

Does anyone have an idea about the problem? Why can't I use 'localhost' instead of 192.168.56.101?

Comment: Is `192.168.56.101` the IP of your physical computer, or of the VM? `localhost` on your physical computer is not the same as `localhost` on the VM, just like it's different from `localhost` on a different computer on your LAN, because that's the idea of a VM: they're acting like two different computers. There are a number of ways to set up networking on VirtualBox, and if the way you have it set up isn't meeting your goals, you can check the documentation for other setups. So the question becomes, what's your real goal?

Comment: 192.168.56.101 is the IP of the VM. But, if  the code is inside of the VM, I should use localhost instead the IP isn't it?

Comment: Yes, inside the VM, `localhost` shoudl be the same `localhost`. But I thought you said you were accessing from your local machine with the web browser? Where's this JavaScript file being run? In the web browser or in a server program?

Comment: My goal is: I want to visualize a map when I write 192.168.56.101:8080/geoserver/www/map.html on the web browser from my local machine.

Comment: The javascript file is running in a server program (Geoserver), and Geoserver is on the VM

Comment: OK, so if this code is not running in the browser, could you please post the code that is?

Comment: Changing localhost by 192.168.56.101 like this: ```url: 'http://192.168.56.101:8080/geoserver/www/ol_map3/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'```

Comment: No, I didn't mean what works or not, you already answered that in your question. I mean, what is the JavaScript code that is in the web page that the browser loads? That code is being run by the browser. As a result, its URLs need to be from the perspective of the web browser, not the server.

Comment: I've checked the code that runs on the browser and it's the same as the server's one. Localhost is present. Probably, that's the problem. The browser thinks that the maptiles are in the local machine instead of the server. Isn't it? That code is the front-end side of the application and it is read by the browser's interpreter.